# If you convert factors into indicator variables, do you treat them as continuous predictors?

Tags: r, regression, modeling

Let's say I have a data matrix X where one feature is a factor with 8 levels. If I change this to be 7 indicator variables of 1's and 0's, do I need to make these columns factors as well? Or if I am training a model on this converted dataset should I just treat these new 1 and 0 values as continuous and scale accordingly?

Comment: This seems to be really a question about what to do in R, although only the tag really makes that explicit. Statistically, indicator variables with 0s and 1s are 0s and 1s, and no more need be side. But please note advice in the Help Center about software-related questions.

Comment: As predictors, binary variables behave statistically the same way be they declared as categorical factors or as continuous "covariates". I prefer to use them as continuous because it saves output.

Answer (score 1):

The indicator variables must be numeric, not factors in the R/SPSS/SAS sense, since that's how design matrices work. Under the hood all linear models convert nominal and ordinal factors to numeric design matrices, but of course you can do this manually as well provided that you make sure they are really numerical inputs. If you don't ensure they are numeric, there is no guarantee that the design matrix constructed by the program will assign the 1's and 0's in the direction you really want.

Comment: So if I have one other continuous variable where the inputs are in the 1000s+, I should then scale the whole dataset so as not to saturate the model?

Comment: For numerical stability it's usually better to center continuous predictors, if that is what you are asking. Not sure what that has to do with model saturation though.

Comment: Formally, 0-1-variables enter the model in exactly the sam way as continuous variabls.  But there is really a difference, mostly glossed over:  binary variables are measured  without error, while continuous varaibles usually comes with a measurement error!

Comment: @kjetil Binary variables are only measured without error if a 1 is never measured as 0 and a 0 is never measured as 1.

Comment: Glen_b:  Yes, but that would be a misclassification, not a meaurement error.  The way to treat it would be different!